# How to write POST REST API with Node.js, Express and SQL DB?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, rest, express

I'm working on a REST API Post request to insert new data into a SQL database, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client
const { request } = require('http');

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'serveraddress',
    database: 'databasename'
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

  //POST API
 app.post("/tag/insert/:tagId/", function(req , res){
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        var stringRequest = "INSERT INTO Tag (tagId, tagStatus) VALUES ("+ req.params.tagId+ ", 1)";
        request.query(stringRequest, function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
    });
})
```

If i try to insert a new tag via browser like "http://localhost:8081/tag/insert/23232" it always says "Cannot GET /tag/insert/23232". What its mean? How solve it?

Comment: You have "/tag/insert/:tagId/" a slash at the end, maybe that's your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are using a `GET` request while you created a `POST` endpoint. I'm not sure if this will work but you can try to change `app.post` to `app.get` so you actually have an `GET` endpoint.

I suggest you read up on HTTP request methods.